# How to just display the data on a dropdown field in yii2.0 but being able to write any option?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I´m more or less new in the Yii 2.0 framework and I´ve been having a serious problem with this situation. I want a dropdown list that shows the differents values I already used in the past but that let me write whatever I want. Like this:

[image]

this is the code:

```
$form->field($model, 'order_idorder')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Order::find()->joinWith('compartmentIdCompartment')->joinWith('hybridIdHybr')->orderBy('idorder')->all(),
            'idorder', 'fullName'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Choose Order')],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]);`
```

The problem with this is that I need to choose one of the options in the dropdown. And I want just the information being display, without the need of actually selecting anything.

Comment: If you do not need to select any option, why do you use the select widget?

Comment: because it displays me the information, what should I use instead?

Comment: A GridView with filtering widgets

Comment: could you help me with an example please?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what are you aiming for here, but my point is that to show model records and be able to search/filter them, the straightforward way to present that info is with a [grid, a table](http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo)

Comment: well the main point here is like having a record of what you used in the past so you can choice an average by the user. For example, if you use 3, 4 and 5 in the past that should be the options, however the user have to write the whatever he wants, Do I explain myself?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is autocomplete and not select widget.

Comment: The issue is that I can´t find the autocomplete by its own, it's always along with the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days searching for the answer, I finally found this:

Demo:
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html

Code:
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=form_widget_editable_select